# wrong sig object get referenced to while executing state in Alloy

Tags: alloy, first-order-logic, declarative-programming

I am new to Alloy. I am trying to formalize a system using Alloy. Here I want to execute certain operations based on the events. For this, I have a list of events that I want to track using enum Event. And I am going through all the State using ordering function of Alloy. In each state, I am taking the mixture object and running the operation.

Problem that I am facing currently is - In my system, I have two sig object - ClassA and ClassB. After executing the alloy code I am generating the flow diagram. Unfortunately, I am noticing my ClassB get referenced to ClassA of Mixture object. I am attaching the diagram

[image]

I am also attaching my full code here. Can anyone help me debugging the problem, please? I have tried to impose different predicate and logic, but none of them worked.

```
open util/ordering[State]


abstract sig Base{
 name: String,
 value : Int
}{
value >= 0
}

sig ClassA extends Base{

}{

name = "Class A"
}

sig ClassB extends Base{


}{
name = "Class B"
}

enum Event {EVENT1, EVENT2}


sig State{

mixture: Mixture
}

sig Mixture{
classA: Base,
classB: Base
} {
    classA != classB
}


fact {
    all s: State, s': s.next{
        s.mixture ! in  s'.*next.mixture
        operation [s.mixture]       

    }
}


pred operation [mixture: Mixture]{
    all ev: Event| ev = EVENT1 => {
        mixture.classA.name = "Class A" => {
                mixture.classA.value = 1    
        }
    }

}

run random {} for 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
sig Mixture{
classA: Base,
classB: Base
}
```

In your diagram, the *relations* are named `classA` and `classB`. Since each can point to any arbitrary `Base`, there's nothing stopping `classA` from pointing to a `ClassB` instance. You probably want something like

```
sig Mixture {
    , classA: ClassA
    , classB: ClassB
}
```

Comment: in 'operation' predicate, I am checking whether mixture.classA.name is equal to ClassA or not. If not I am not doing anything. Shouldn't it stop assigning the mixture.classA to ClassB?

Comment: I know your suggestion will work. But here I need to make it more generalize. In my case, there will be ClassA1, ClassB1 extending the base class. So, in my case, I cannot take classA as classA type. Rather I need to take as a parent class. Am I able to clarify my problem?